# How to make 3 column output using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have XML file that looks like this:

```
<platz>
  <platzdesc>
    <code>1</code>
    <name>Alle</name>
  </platzdesc>
  <platzdesc>
    <code>2</code>
    <name>Gold</name>
  </platzdesc>
</platz>
```

I need to write XSLT file to transform this XML into 3 column output. As I am not very good at XSLT can you please help me, I have tried various things but non of them work. Output is not HTML page but PDF.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
<fo:block padding-before = "8pt" padding-start ="50pt">
  <xsl:for-each select="root/platz/platzdesc">
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(code,' - ', name)" />
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:for-each>
</fo:block>
```

I am working on a better solution but your help is welcome.

Comment: Can you show an example of the XML you want to generate (the actual XSL-FO XML tags) and the XSLT you've tried so far?

Comment: You should use fo:table format to get output into multiple columns.

Comment: @NavinRawat - can you be more precise?

Comment: For code, please post text, not images.

Comment: @kjhughes - I would, but how? If I paste in the XML it is automatically transformed to something else that browser can read.

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/234215)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

After a lot of misery, a solution was born. Enjoy![image]

ZOOM IN PLEASE TO SEE IT!

Comment: It looks like you used @Mathias answer. If so you should consider marking his answer with the green check mark to show that he was able to answer your question. Also, your question and answer needs to contain text instead of images for code or else your question might get closed for not containing the necessary information.

Comment: Well, if I used Mathias solution it would be the same as mine, at least logically and it is not. Mathias solution can not print rows dynamically, it is fixed, aka less desirable.

Comment: This is not about desirability, I'd say. You did not reveal your intention behind the question and therefore my answer is a general one. Anyway, if my answer was helpful to you (i.e. set you on the right track) please mark it as answer. Or else, mark your own answer and thereby close the question.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - I tried to mark my own answer as correct but it wont let me as I have to way 2 days for accepting my own answer. Please, don't feel offended, I am just saying that dynamically is always more desirable then fixed solution, that's all and thank you, you did help me

Comment: That image is unreadable. Could you please replace it with the actual code in text form?

Comment: Ok ,as soon as I catch some time, no problem

Answer (score 3):

As suggested already by @Navin Ravat, you could use a table.

This is the general structure of a table in XSL-FO:

```
<fo:table xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
 <fo:table-column width="50mm"/>
 <fo:table-column width="50mm"/>
 <fo:table-column width="50mm"/>
 <fo:table-body>
  <fo:table-row>
     <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block/>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block/>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block/>
     </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
 </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

Above is a simple example table with just one row, you can add more of course. Now you have to incorporate this structure into your XSLT stylesheet. For instance, like this:

```
<xsl:element name="fo:table">
  <xsl:element name="fo:table-column">
    <xsl:attribute name="width">50mm</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="fo:table-column">
    <xsl:attribute name="width">50mm</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="fo:table-column">
    <xsl:attribute name="width">50mm</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="fo:table-body">
    <xsl:element name="fo:table-row">
      <xsl:element name="fo:table-cell">
        <xsl:element name="fo:block">
          <xsl:value-of select="platz/platzdesc[code=2]"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```